# Why does this small sql change in the where clause of an innerjoin cause a huge performance improvement?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Background:

We narrowed down some performance issues in our ERP to one SQL statement.  Our support person made one small change to the SQL statment and performance improved.  The back-end is Microsoft Access.  (yes I know, yes it's embarrassing, no I have no choice in the matter)

We went from 75% of the time the statement would take 90 seconds to run, and 25% 2-3 seconds to 100% of the time 2-3 seconds.

The POHDR table is large 20,000 plus rows, SUPPNAME is under 1000.  Both tables have the vnum field indexed.

SQL statements below, but all that changed is the Where clause uses SUPPNAME.vnum instead of POHDR.vnum.

BEFORE:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW POHDR.*, 
                   SUPPNAME.SNAME1,
                   suppname.sname1 & chr(13) & chr(10) & POHDR.vnum as SUPPFLD 
    FROM POHDR 
        INNER JOIN SUPPNAME 
            ON POHDR.VNUM = SUPPNAME.VNUM 
    WHERE ((POHDR.VNUM= '20023' AND POHDR.RECDATE Is Null))  
        AND [POHDR].[CANCEL] Is Null and ((POHDR.CLOSED=No)) 
    order by IIf(InStr(PO,'-'),Left(PO,InStr(PO,'-')) & '_' & Mid(PO,InStr(PO,'-')),PO)
```

AFTER:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW POHDR.*, 
                   SUPPNAME.SNAME1,
                   suppname.sname1 & chr(13) & chr(10) & POHDR.vnum as SUPPFLD 
    FROM POHDR 
        INNER JOIN SUPPNAME 
            ON POHDR.VNUM = SUPPNAME.VNUM 
    WHERE ((SUPPNAME.VNUM= '26037' AND POHDR.RECDATE Is Null))  
        AND [POHDR].[CANCEL] Is Null 
        and ((POHDR.CLOSED=No)) 
    order by IIf(InStr(PO,'-'),Left(PO,InStr(PO,'-')) & '_' & Mid(PO,InStr(PO,'-')),PO)
```

Does changing where the vnum is selected to a smaller table with less or no duplication of the vnum really make that big of a difference, or is there something else going on?

thanks, Brian the Curious.

p.s.  Also, I did not write or have control of this sql statment.  And not sure exactly what is going on with the if in the order by clause either.

Comment: Google "JETSHOWPLAN".  Run each query and compare the results in the Showplan.out file.  Post the results here as part of your question (if they still don't make sense to you) or as an answer (if you understand what's going on and want to share it with the rest of us).

Comment: While you're doing that, you might also want to try a third query: `... FROM POHDR, SUPPNAME WHERE POHDR.VNUM='26037' AND SUPPNAME.VNUM='26037' ...`

Comment: Of course, we are taking for granted that both POHDR.VNUM and SUPPNAME.VNUM are indexed ... Is there some other contraint such as unique value, etc?

Comment: Unless MS Access is different, I thought using an * in the select query hinders index performance (bookmark lookup vs index seek because it won't find a non-clustered index that satisfies "*").

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a very good "WHY" answer to your question, other than the fact that changing that WHERE clause caused a different query plan to be chosen by the optimizer.

The optimizer can choose a query plan based on many factors (indexes, statistics, black magic, etc). As long as you've got good indexes, the best you can usually do is carefully test different similar versions of the query, and compare the query plans they generate.

Answer (score 0):

The key in this kind of query optimization is indexing - so first thing to check if all fields are indexed, in particular SUPPNAME.VNUM and POHDR.VNUM.

Then the second, of course, is the number of records in each table that satisfy each of these conditions. If there is only one SUPPNAME.VNUM= '26037' it could eliminate a lot of POHDR.VNUM= '20023' which would fail on other criteria, which then does not need to be executed.

But without seeing the structure of your DB and data in it, I would not make any definite conclusions.